# Starting PowerShell Script with Process.Start closes PowerShell with no error

Tags: c#, powershell, windows-10, execution

I'm writing a small app in C# that calls various PowerShell scripts to configure a computer.

I'm having an issue now that I don't think I was having just a couple weeks back when I worked on it last.

When I call these scripts from C# a PowerShell window opens extremely briefly and then closes. I thought perhaps there was an error in my PS script, but no- if I do a Start-Transcript at the beginning I still get no output, so it's clearly not even starting to run my scripts.

My code:

`Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ", @"C:\Thunder\Scripts\3-BitLockerEnable.ps1");`

I thought maybe Execution Policy was the problem, but it's set to unrestricted. I made sure the file path was right- simply removing the PowerShell call lets me check, and it opens the ps1 file in Notepad fine without that line.

Any help appreciated, I'm not sure where I've made a mistake. I could have sworn this exact code was working fine a couple weeks ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in PowerShell object:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Thunder\Scripts\3-BitLockerEnable.ps1")).Invoke();
```

Comment: Running it as you suggested gives:

```PSSnapInException: System error.
System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell.LoadMshSnapinAssembly (System.Management.Automation.PSSnapInInfo mshsnapinInfo) (at <a866df73fe6e416dad3eec8d3078bb68>:0)```

And several more lines. Really generic error so I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: I'm using System.Management.Automation and Microsoft.PowerShell and Microsoft.Powershell.Commands, not sure which specifically or if anything more is needed for this to work.